# How to solve the boxplot error "invalid first Argument"?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have tried to make a boxplot out of this dataset - https://www.kaggle.com/freecodecamp/2016-new-coder-survey-/scripts, but I get an error message

> "Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response]), ...) : invalid first argument"

I've cleaned the NAs, but it doesn't work. Maybe, you know what's the problem?
For a record, I tried converting Age to numeric and Employment Field to factor - still doesn't work..

```
boxplot(Age ~ EmploymentField, data = newCoders,
    col = brewer.pal(5, "Set1"),
    whisklty = 1,
    staplelty = 0,
    main = "Age of New Coders vs Employment Field",
    xlab = "Employment Field",
    outcol = brewer.pal(5, "Set1"),
    outpch = 16, #outlier symbol
    ylab = "Age")
```

Comment: Could you provide a brief [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) data set? Using `dput` could help.

Comment: Can you edit post  with the output of `dput(newCoders[c("Age", "EmploymentField")])` please, or if that is too large then `str(newCoders[c("Age", "EmploymentField")])`

Comment: Would have expected age to already be numeric. What does str(newCoders) return now?

Comment: Please include data and code in your question. Avoid linking to off-site resources.

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for this error are that your response variable is either completely missing, non-numeric, or has been otherwise called incorrectly. Try using the summarize command to check that the data you are plotting have been correctly called, are non-missing, and are indeed numeric.

Answer (score 0):

**anova works, but boxplot doesnt:**
*Error in boxplot.default(split(mf[[response]], mf[-response], drop = drop,  :
invalid first argument*

`enter code here`ContAttr_moist<-unlist(Variety[,6])
CatgAttr2_varietyCode<-unlist(Variety[,2])
CatgAttr1_parts<-unlist(Variety$parts)
ANOVA_2way_moist<-aov(ContAttr_moist~factor(CatgAttr2_varietyCode)*factor(CatgAttr1_parts))
ANOVA_2way_protein<-aov(ContAttr_protein~factor(CatgAttr2_varietyCode)*factor(CatgAttr1_parts))
ANOVA_2way_gluten<-aov(ContAttr_gluten~factor(CatgAttr2_varietyCode)*factor(CatgAttr1_parts))

pdf(file="two-way ANOVA_moisture.pdf")

par(mfrow = c(7,1))

boxplot(ContAttr_moist~CatgAttr1_parts, subset = (CatgAttr2_varietyCode == 0),
xlab = "variety", ylab = "moisture", main="part 0")

boxplot(unlist(Variety[,6])~unlist(Variety$parts), subset = (CatgAttr2_varietyCode == 0),
xlab = "variety", ylab = "moisture", main="part 0")

dev.off()

Comment: Please edit your answer so your code is correctly in a codeblock. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks